# ionic app - APNS & GCM to multiple apps from one server

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

we have an app built in ionic that sends out push notifications.

We are now making branded versions of the same app for different companies that share the same user & code base.

The way we are currently sending out notifications is a cron job that runs a PHP script every minute which connects to a MySQL Database to find new notifications that need to be push out, however we are willing to change this if anyone has a better suggestion.

Having one server needing to send out notifications to multiple apps is the problem we are facing. If we open and close connections to APNS for each app every time we run our push cron job, we fear Apple will see it as a DDOS attack and block it.

The only other solution we can think of is making a new server on AWS for each branded app and having them send notifications out for only one app each. That way they would each have their own IP Address and Apple wouldn't pick it up as a DDOS attack.

We looked into AWS SNS but the only tutorials are for Swift, Obj-C & Android. Our app is fully made on ionic meaning its written in Angular so none of these tutorials are helpful for us.

I've been searching Google for awhile with no valuable information.

Please answer with a way to accomplish sending notifications to multiple apps. Thanks in advance for reading!

Comment: You may want to consider changing the tags of this question, as your client apps being Ionic Framework may not be relevant, and it may help to know what your server is, e.g. Node.js, since any resolution would be sender/server side. One suggestion comes to mind if you don't get a good answer: consider a queuing service to stagger the calls with some delays?

Comment: @NeilCresswell Thanks for the response, any suggestions on relevant tags for this? The way we send out push notifications is currently on a cron job running a PHP script connecting to a MySQL database. I will update the question with this information.

Comment: Maybe remove ionic-framework and add tags for PHP and cron? Sorry not familiar with that approach. I also write Ionic apps (Android and iOS) with push notifications, but my API service hooking in is Node.js-based. Perhaps take a look at SQS? Not familiar with that either, hence not posting an answer here. Just throwing some ideas out.